# I'm using a python to idl bridge in a python script, but get the following error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pythonidl36'

Tags: python, idl

Added:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('<IDL_DIR>/lib/bridges')
from idlpy import *
```

to the python script (3.6) and changed the IDL_DIR to `/opt/IDL/bin/` and get the following error(s):

```
python3 /home/phaines/climate/data/download_stations_test6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/IDL/idl/lib/bridges/idlpy.py", line 29, in <module>
    pyidl = import_module(idllibrary)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pythonidl36'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/phaines/climate/data/download_stations_test6", line 66, in <module>
    from idlpy import *
  File "/opt/IDL/idl/lib/bridges/idlpy.py", line 43, in <module>
    pyidl = import_module(idllibrary)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pythonidl36'
```

Comment: Are you literally typing in '<IDL_DIR>'?  Python has no idea what that is.  You need to modify that to be the directory where your IDL is installed.

Comment: I used the actual python address. It turned out that when using IDL 8.9, you need Python 3.8, 3.9. 3.10.    So, a 3.8 is available, used it, but now get :  No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath